# modifying scantool.exe so i can read Freeze Frame data

Tags: obd-ii

I have rebuilt scantool.exe from source and I want to add freeze frame capture.
I haven't been able to find details on what the returned packet looks like. descriptions say it is just like mode 1 but are all supported PIDS returned at once or do each have to be queried. how do i know how many PIDS are in freeze frame along with DTC.   Looking for a good programming document which describes query and response packets